# Relatively maximal sum-free subsets in finite groups

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, extremal-combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

> Suppose $G$ is a group, $S \subset G$. Let’s call $S$ *sum-free* iff $\forall a, b \in S$ we have $ab \notin S$. What  is the value of $c := \sup\{\frac{|A|}{|G|}| $G$ \text{ is a finite group, } A \subset G \text{ is sum-free}\}$?

It is not hard to see, that $c \geq \frac{1}{2}$. Indeed, in order to achieve it one can simply take any group $G$ with a subgroup $H$ of index $2$. $G \setminus H$ will be sum-free in that case. However, I suspect that $c$ can be much larger…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sum-free subset $S$ of $G$ cannot have more than $\frac{1}{2}|G|$ elements. Thus $c\leq\frac{1}{2}$.

*Proof.* Indeed, fix $s\in S$ and consider

$$f:G\to G$$
$$f(g)=gs$$

Since $S$ is sum-free then $f(S)\subseteq G-S$ which obviously implies $|f(S)|\leq |G-S|$. Since $f$ is a bijection then $|S|=|f(S)|$ and thus $$|S|=|f(S)|\leq |G-S|=|G|-|S|$$ which finally leads to $$|S|\leq\frac{1}{2}|G|$$

Comment: Very nice answer, +1 from me!